# Tomcat for VSCode debugger not showing variable values during step

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I have these Java extensions installed for VSCode:

> Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat  version 0.41.0 https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java
>
> Tomcat for Java  version 0.11.1 https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat
>
> Debugger for Java version 0.170 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug

Steps to reproduce:

- Open project
- Build project into a .war
- Debug .war on Tomcat Server
- Set Breakpoint
- Open in Browser

When running the code stops at the breakpoint, and I'm able to step through OK - But does not show variables/values in Variable pane at left on mouse-over.

```java
package src.ServletTest;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private String msg;
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        msg = "Hello World!"; ***** I can mouseover and see variable value at this breakpoint
    }

    //@Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {



        response.setContentType("text/html");   ***** but once inside doGet I cannot see any of these local variable vaules
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


            String s1 = "Hiya";
            String s2 = "Ya!";
            String s3 = s1 + s2;
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head><title>Java Home Page</title></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Java says Hi to you!</h1>");
            out.println(s3 + msg);
```

Comment: Please consider adding links to the plugin being used and some version info.

Comment: Hi Folks, a quick followup...I used the Maven plugin for VSCode and am now able to debug through the application A-OK, this is satisfactory for my needs.